# Redeclared class name class-key

Tags: c++, templates

The following quote is from `14.5.1/4 [temp.class]`:

> In a redeclaration, partial specialization, explicit specialization or
>   explicit instantiation of a class template, the *class-key* shall agree
>   in kind with the original class template declaration

I thought it meant that we cannot declare an explicit specialization with another class key, for instance:

```
template <class T, class W>
struct A
{
    void foo();
};

template <class T, class W>
class A<T*, W>                 // Should have printed an error
{
    void foo();
};
```

**[DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8249583cfcd03b6f)**

But it works fine. So what's the point of that rule?

Comment: @vsoftco So what is the boundary of that completely agreement?

Comment: @vsoftco BTW, I was talking about a class-key. I declared the primary template with struct, but partial specialization with class.

Comment: I suspect that by "kind" what they meant was that `class` and `struct` are the same kind and `union` is different, but I'm not sure.

Comment: FWIW, compiling `class B; struct B{};` with `g++ -Wall` produces no warning but Visual Studio 2010 reports:  "warning C4099: 'B' : type name first seen using 'class' now seen using 'struct'"

Comment: @DmitryFucintv I see now what you meant, first I thought you were talking about the parameter. Just disregard my comment, will erase it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right after the quoted sentence is a reference to [dcl.type.elab]. [dcl.type.elab]/p3 describes what "agree in kind" means:

> The *class-key* or `enum` keyword present in the
>   *elaborated-type-specifier* shall agree in kind with the declaration to which the name in the *elaborated-type-specifier* refers.  [...]
>   Thus, in any *elaborated-type-specifier*, the `enum` keyword shall be
>   used to refer to an enumeration (7.2), the `union` *class-key* shall
>   be used to refer to a union (Clause 9), and either the `class` or
>   `struct` *class-key* shall be used to refer to a class (Clause 9)
>   declared using the `class` or `struct` *class-key*.

In other words, if the primary template is a union, the "redeclaration, partial specialization, explicit specialization or explicit instantiation" must use `union`; otherwise it can use either `class` or `struct`, but not `union`.

Comment: so if you use `class` in primary template and `struct` for the specialization, the visibility is also changed? I.e. default `private` becomes default `public`? This seems to create lots of confusion.

Comment: @vsoftco Correct, the accessibility depends on the *class-key* used for the definition.

Comment: have to say that I really don't see why one would want this "feature" and why is it accepted by the standard

Comment: @vsoftco So that your specialization code doesn't depend on whether the primary template is defined with `class` or `struct`? This can be important when you are specializing someone else's template (e.g., a template in the standard library).

Comment: @T.C. I checked this out, [link](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3300ddfeef0a277a) and it worked. But what do you know that from? Maybe you could point me out to the chapter?

Comment: @DmitryFucintv [temp.class.spec] says that each partial specialization is a distinct template. [class.access]/p3 says that the keyword used in the class definition is what controls default accessibility.